I use react-native-ble-manager. When assembling app as Release startNotification does not work, when as Debug - works well
IF I BUILD AN APP AS "DEBUG" - IT WORKS WELL, IF I BUILD AN APP AS A RELEASE - IT DO NOT WORK
I use a smartphone Oppo Reno 5 with Android 13 for testing.
The device (smartwatch) connects via BLE and the Wrote command is successful.
I made a subscription to notifications - this.BLEService.startNotification(this.device.id, appConfig.UUID_S, appConfig.UUID_C_1);
But it doesn't work - this.bleManagerEmitter.addListener('BleManagerDidUpdateValueForCharacteristic', ({value, device, characteristic, service}, ...)
Events do not come
My AndroidManifest:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />

